# Tables not found in SQL database schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-administration

We're using SQL Server Management Studio 10.0 with Business Objects 4.1 for reporting. We're facing an issue where none of our reports were running, and every time it gave the error:

> Database Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.. (IES 10901)

We drilled down the issue further and noticed that it was because some of the table in the SQL query were not valid. On running a select statement on the concerned tables, we get the error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.tablename'

I am not able to see these tables in the concerned schema and not able to find any related logs as well to see if someone dropped them by mistake. I don't know much about administration, can someone provide useful links or any thoughts on how to find those tables please?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the correct database?  Try fully qualifying the tablenames like this: `databasename.schemaname.tablename`

Comment: Sounds like you might have corrupted your database, this question would probably fair better on [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hopefully you were taking regular backups. Restore one of them and see if the tables are there.

Comment: Hi Dave, Yes I tried querying using the database name as well though I didn't explicitly mention it here.

Comment: The DB is backed up every weekend, so if we restore the latest backed up version, we would lose 4 days data? Because, everything was working fine until last evening. I am not sure if any of the SQL server processes got interrupted which cause the tables to be dropped. Its very unlikely. Can we know if the tables were dropped at all? I tried running SELECT * FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) WHERE [transaction name] IN ('DROPOBJ') but this didnt return any result.

Comment: Do all the tables actually belong to the DBO schema? Sometimes when I have encountered this problem, it was because the table belonged to some other schema, e.g. [dbname].[dbuser].[table] instead of [dbname].[dbo].[table]

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure they belong to the DBO schema, because the queries from our Business Objects reports still point to those missing tables, which say they belong to the dbo schema :(

Comment: select * from sys.tables where name = 'tableName' will tell you if the tables actually exist, and which schema they are part of (Assuming you have permissions to query the system tables.  The fn_dblog function only works to find if something was dropped and won't get your data back.  Also, it will only return results if that action is still part of the active log.

Comment: This is a reporting system, how often is it updated?  If it's daily and follows a drop/recreate pattern it's possible that process encountered an error.  Do you know any information on this?

Comment: I tried the "select * from sys.tables" as well, and I cant see the table names there and I do have admin permissions. There are daily jobs that load this database, and I checked that todays job had failed (on the job monitor) with the same error. So, still trying to debug.